# How do you setup the css-loader in Laravel+Vue?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vuetify.js, css-loader, vue-loader

I'm trying to install the Material Design Icons so I don't need to use the CDNs as per explainned here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#icons

I have no idea how to setup the "css-loader" in my laravel.mix - I've tried samples from some github threads and that would compile the Icons, but my templates stopped rendering